# How to resolve Minimal BASH-Like line editing is supported

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, bootable-media

I'm trying to migrate from windows to ubuntu, so I tried to make a bootable usb using **rufus** and later on using **universal usb installer** in both the cases after selecting boot device I'm getting this error

> Minimal BASH-Like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
>   lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
>   device or file completions.

can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the input! Yes indeed, the problem was the .iso file that was created by "Startup Disk Creator".

- I installed balenaEtcher
- Created a new .iso on my USB
- The installation executed flawlessly

Although I used Startup Disk Creator in the past with success, I shall never use it again! Lesson learned!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).