# GRUB Message Encountered Installing Ubuntu 22.04 (from USB) onto a Windows 10 System

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, installation, grub

I have a problem similar to the one described at:

[How to resolve Minimal BASH-Like line editing is supported](https://superuser.com/questions/1447101/how-to-resolve-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported)

I had a fresh install of Windows 10 on a computer (Intel NUC10i7FNHN that I just purchased). I wanted to fresh install Ubuntu 22.04 and remove Windows 10. Did the following...

- Downloaded the ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso file from the Ubuntu site.
- Formatted a USB using 'Startup Disk Creator'
- Copied the .iso to the USB
- Inserted the USB into the computer
- Powered up
- Set UEFI to use the USB as the primary boot device
- Exited UEFI, continued the boot process, and saw the following grub related message

  ```
  GNU GRUB version 2.06
  Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
  grub> _
  ```
- I booted into Windows 10 and went into the Settings options.
- Selected the option to disable UEFI secure boot.
- Verified that secure boot was indeed disabled and the USB was the primary boot source
- Repeated the above process again, attempting to boot Ubuntu from the USB.
- Same grub message as shown above.

I am not sure if this is an Ubuntu .iso issue or possibly a Windows 10 related issue. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: See if [this method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/) helps.

Comment: To make installation/live media in Windows you can use many tools like Balena Etcher or Rufus with a proven track record. Your 2nd and 3rd bullet points makes little to no sense at all. Firstly, 'Startup Disk Creator' AFAIK is Linux software but your doing it in Windows??? Secondly, it's a one-step process and calling it "format" it's a stretch. So what doesn't make sense is "formatted" then "copied the ISO" (???) I suspect you did something wrong and there's absolutely NO point is going forward with it as it is now. Do it again properly and it should work (...)

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview This tutorial suggests Rufus which is fine but also has too many options for beginners IMO. Again, you perhaps should use something like Balena Etcher which is 1-2-3, done! 1. select the ISO, 2. select the target USB drive, 3. "burn".

Comment: Also Secure Boot has NOTHING to do with it.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the input! Indeed the .iso created by the "Startup Disk Creator" program was the problem. I installed balenaEtcher, made a new .iso, and the installation executed flawlessly. I had used Startup Disk Creator in the past with success. Never again! Lesson learned!